# PHP mail function not sending email

Tags: php, ajax, email

I'm trying to send a basic email using the PHP mail function and AJAX.
There are no errors, but the email doesn't get sent.
Here is my AJAX function:

```
<script language="javascript">
function sendMail(email){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/mail.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert("entrei");
        document.getElementById("email").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", url+"?email=" + email, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
    <?php
$Name = "Da Duder"; //senders name 
$email = "adamsilva01@gmail.com"; //senders e-mail adress 
$recipient = "adamsilva01@gmail.com"; //recipient 
$mail_body = "The text for the mail..."; //mail body 
$subject = "Subject for reviever"; //subject 
$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields 
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); //mail command :) 
?>
```

Anybody know what's wrong?

EDIT.:Btw, this is my php.ini mail config and I have it all set up in XAMPP:

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
```

EDIT2.:I changed my PHP code and now I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ev7sm64500334wjb.47 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\path\public_html\mailtest.php on line 10
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple send with no logic and no ajax to see if that gets sent?
ie: mail( 'nobody@example.com','test','a basic test');

Comment: yeah, using this code: <?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('myemail@email.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>

Comment: You're trying to send using a secure server. You'll need something more than just `mail` to send an email using Gmail.

Comment: @M1ke I used Gmail because it was the first one that I found. I want to send email through localhost. How do I do that?

Comment: If you remove the `ini_set` function calls you'll try and send using your local server. This will require the server to have `mailutils` installed as mentioned in my first answer. If you don't have root access to the server try my other answer which shows how you can use Gmail.

Comment: Then, will the code above work if I put it on the live server of the website?

Comment: **WARNING** Your current implementation will give the ability for email enumeration. For example, if you implement the same logic for password recovery, someone can change the passwords for users which will be annoying to your users. (Probably do it for the lulz, unless the attacker can access peoples e-mail accounts). *Just a heads up!*

Answer (score 0):

So if we assume you can run that PHP script natively and it returns `failed`...

Are you able to access the server itself (root)? Most likely you don't have mail modules installed locally. If the server is Debian-based (e.g. Ubuntu) run `apt-get install mailutils` and try again.

(*If running the function doesn't return failed, what does it return?*)

Comment: it returns 1, which I assume means success

Comment: Your script should echo "No email", "success" or "failed".  Which one does it output? (If it doesn't output any of these then there are errors elsewhere).

Comment: There is no `echo 1` line in your code; it would seem that code outside of what is posted is preventing your code from running. Is that code the entirety of `mail.php`? Try removing the `return` statements and running it; I have no idea why they'd cause it to print "1" but who knows.

Comment: With the 'return' statements, I echoed '$success' and it returned 1Success, without the 'return' statements, it returns nothing

Comment: If that's a whole script there should be nothing to return. What code is calling this block?

Comment: it's a button
`<button id="postEmail" onclick="sendMail(email.value)">Ok</button>`

Comment: Let's ignore your JavaScript for now. We're saying to run the PHP file natively, i.e. navigate to `http://localhost/email.php?email=name@domain.com` (or whatever the file name is) and see what it outputs.

Comment: I changed my PHP code, please check above to see the new code and the error it gives

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send using a secure server. You'll need something more than just `mail` to send an email using Gmail.

You can use the open source (and very popular) [PHP mailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to do this.

Here is a project on GitHub which has the whole process of using PHPMailer and sending using Gmail: https://github.com/abusalam/GMail-SMTP

Comment: **TIP:** IIRC, you need to apply a setting to your gmail account. [See step 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server)